TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. AerConfig, arg0: list[list[tuple[tuple[int, int], list[float]]]]) -> None
I have a function run, that uses parameter_binds


def run(self, i):
        params = i
        backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')            
        param_binds = [{self.thetas[k] : params[k].item() for k in range(NUM_QUBITS)}]
        print(param_binds)
        job_sim = backend.run(self.circuit,
                              shots=self.shots,
                              parameter_binds = param_binds)#[{self.thetas[k] : params[k].item() for k in range(2*NUM_QUBITS)}])
        result_sim = job_sim.result()
        counts = result_sim.get_counts(self.circuit)
        return self.N_qubit_expectation_Z(counts,self.shots,NUM_QUBITS)



that will be then used for the following


circuit = QiskitCircuit(NUM_QUBITS, SIMULATOR, NUM_SHOTS)
print('Expected value for rotation [pi/4]: {}'.format(circuit.run(torch.Tensor([np.pi/4]*NUM_QUBITS))))



but I have this error, and no matter what changes I do for the parameter list, it appears again or claims that the list is unhashable


TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: qiskit_aer.backends.controller_wrappers.AerConfig, arg0: list[list[tuple[tuple[int, int], list[float]]]]) -> None

Invoked with: <qiskit_aer.backends.controller_wrappers.AerConfig object at 0x000002222C60EC30>, [[[(4, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(5, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(6, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(7, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(11, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(12, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(13, 0), 0.7853981852531433], [(14, 0), 0.7853981852531433]]]



Any ideas?

At first, the incompatibility issue in the parameter definition line should be solved by casting, because data types should be emphasized clearly as:
pb = [{str(self.thetas[k]) : float(params[k].item()) for k in range(NUM_QUBITS)}]

However, this is not everything, because there is a bug in the aerbackend.py file, which keeps causing problems as the read values are always returning null, thus the append_param_values method should be updated as the following:
def append_param_values(index, bind_pos, param):
    if param in binds:
        parameterizations.append([(index, bind_pos), binds[param]])
    elif isinstance(param, ParameterExpression):
        # If parameter expression has no unbound parameters
        # it's already bound and should be skipped
        if not param.parameters:
            return
        if not binds:
            raise AerError("The element of parameter_binds is empty.")
        len_vals = len(binds.values())
        bind_list = []
        for i in range(len_vals):
            bind_dict = {}
            for parameter in  binds.keys():
                for params in param.parameters :
                    if str(parameter)==str(params):
                        if isinstance(binds[parameter], float):
                            bind_dict[params] = binds[parameter]
                    break
            bind_list.append(bind_dict)
        bound_values = [float(param.bind(x)) for x in bind_list]
        parameterizations.append([(index, bind_pos), bound_values])

